# get changing value from readonly textarea by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `readonly` textarea which its value keep changing. Now I want the page keeps updating its value and return the result if it matches with the provided string or not. Here is what I tried but it's not working

```
var string = "This is my house";

    $('#textarea').bind('input', function() { 

    if ($(this).val() === string.trim()) {
        $('#message').html('matching').css('color', 'green');       
    } else $('#message').html('not matching').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Is there any error? We can't help you with incomplete information.

Comment: I'm so tempted to edit it, why can't I :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't listen to the `input` event as the textarea is `readonly`, what you can do though is trigger the `input` - *or any other event*- using `.trigger()` in same code that changes the text content of the textarea

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h98fgq6q/1/)

```js
var string = "This is my house", ta = $('#textarea'), msg = $('#message'),
    newContent = 'just dummy text'; // replacement text, change it to see the result

ta.on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === string.trim()) { msg.html('matching').css('color', 'green'); } 
  else { msg.html('not matching').css('color', 'red'); }
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  ta.text(newContent).trigger('input'); // trigger input event as text content is changed
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Change it</button><br>
<textarea readonly name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="5">This is my house</textarea>
<hr><div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are right about the `readonly` area, can I just trigger the input event as long as the textarea's value change because it will just automatically change? not through the click

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/h98fgq6q/2/), I've already tried to listen for the regular `input` and `change` events but it doesn't work unless I trigger it programmatically using the `trigger()` function.. so all you need is where you have your code to update the text of the `textarea` just add the `trigger()` function and it'll work just fine.

Comment: "*can I just trigger the input event as long as the textarea's value change because it will just automatically change? not through the click*" this is exactly why I used `trigger()` function in my answer, for details please have a look at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```js
var string = 'This is my house';
var array = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipisicing elit', 'This is my house', 'quae aperiam solut'];
var counter = 0;

$('textarea').click(function() {
   if(array[counter] == string.trim()) {
     $('.result').text('Matching').css('color', 'green');
   } else {
     $('.result').text('Not matching').css('color', 'red');
   }
   
   $('textarea').text(array[counter]);
   counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea readonly placeholder="Click Me" class="textArea"></textarea>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i am really appreciated. In my case, the textarea's content will take the value from user's voice (just like google web speech API) so the content just .. automatically change. Do we have any way to trigger the "matching check" when the TA's content change?

Comment: @user2986673 You can try `$('textarea').change(function(){ });`